# OAuth google connection in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I was searching google a lot these days but I couldn't found proper solution.
In my ASP.NET MVC application I want to use external log in so that the users can log via their google accounts. At first at localhost in AuthConfig.cs file I used:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();
```

Then when moving on the server I got the error: [image: error]

So I found a lot of links leading to creating a project on [this link](https://console.developers.google.com) and I created one, but I still can not figure out where and how to add the credentials. In my AuthConfig.cs file I have this structure so far:

```
    public static void RegisterAuth()
    {
        //OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();
    }
```

and I can not use the format that starts with (I found this i a few places):

```
    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(
     clientId: "000-000.apps.googleusercontent.com",
     clientSecret: "00000000000");
```

because that **app** is not part of my file at all. Can anyone give me a direction how I should continue?

Comment: Try using Microsoft.Owin.Security, Owin.Security.Providers packages to support your OAuth Google.http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864

Comment: The `app` stuff is from is from OWIN, which the newer ASP.NET Identity utilizes. You're still using membership, and even if you can bootstrap OWIN support into that, it's going to be a big headache. Confine your searches to MVC 4/SimpleMembership/etc. to avoid getting mixed info from the new Identity stuff. Or, if you can, upgrade. Identity is night and day better than membership, but it's not trivial to switch.

Answer (score 0):

The new OWIN/ASP.NET Identity looks good. I also tried the walk through that DSR mentioned, it is pretty easy.

You can take a look at:
http://www.asp.net/identity

Which has a link to the good walk through about OAuth mentioned in the comments, but also this one, about **adding Identity to an existing project**:
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project